# Regex: Is there something else I should be using to achieve what I want?

Tags: javascript, regex, file-extension

Based off lots of examples from searching, I have created a regex that I use (as a fallback) to parse direct file links from HTML source:

```
/((?:(?:https?%3A%2F%2F)(?:www\.)?(?:\S+)%2F|(?:https?:\/\/)(?:www\.)?(?:\S+)\/)(?:.*)?\.(mp4|mkv|wmv|m4v|mov|avi|flv|webm|flac|mka|m4a|aac|ogg)(?=[^.]*$))/igm
```

My problem is that it fails on lines that have more than one link in them. I know that parsing HTML using a regex even as a fallback is frowned upon so, what else could I use to find ALL direct file links in a page's source? (This means links hidden in inline JavaScript, video source tags and the like; not just what `document.links` returns.)

*If there are not any better suggestions, can someone help me fix the regex to achieve what I want?*

The regex should follow these guidelines:

- Return the URL in group one and the file extension in group two
- Find both encoded and decoded URLs
- Find specific file extensions (namely video and audio)
- Tolerate multi-level file extensions
- Tolerate spaces in the URL
- Allow any domain, both secure and non-secure, with or without "www" for the HTTP scheme
- Find all URLs regardless of their location in the HTML source
- Be compatible with JavaScript

Some examples that *should* be matched:

```
http://test.com/test.mkv
http://test.com/test/test.jpg.mkv
https://test.com/test.mkv?test=test
http%3A%2F%2Ftest.com%2Ftest.mkv%3Ftest%3Dtest
https%3A%2F%2Ftest.com%2Ftest.jpg.mkv%3Ftest%3Dtest.mkv
http://test.com/t est.mkv__some__random__string__http://test.com/test.mkv
```

The last example should match the two URLs but, not the `__some__random__string__`.

Some examples that *should not* be matched:

```
http://test.com/test.mkv.jpg
http://test.com/test.mkv/test.jpg
https://test.com/test.mkv.jpg?test=test.mkv
http%3A%2F%2Ftest.com%2Ftest.mkv.jpg
https%3A%2F%2Ftest.com%2Ftest.mkv.jpg%3Ftest%3Dtest.mkv
http://test.com/t est.mkv__some__random__string__http://test.com/test.mkv.jpg
```

The last example should match only the first URL, before `__some__random__string__`.

You can play with the regex and an example of some HTML source that partially fails at: http://regexr.com/3dbac

Comment: Just FYI: your `(?:.*)?` matches across the link boundaries, you can either use `\S*` or a more restrictive `[^\s>]*`

Comment: Oops... I forgot to mention I wanted to support spaces in a link. I originally had the `\S*`, but changed it to what I thought would support spaces before posting. The troublesome parts of the regex seem to be the spaces and the multi-level file extension requirements. I can't figure it out. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Please give your question a title which describes what it is about.

Comment: My actual question seems to have gotten lost I guess. My question is what the title states: Is there something else I should be using to achieve what I want other than a regex? The top half of the question addresses this.

I only included the info about the regex because **if** there is not any other way to achieve this, I want to fix the regex.

What would you suggest I change the title to? Feel free to edit yourself if you'd like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if we take into account only the sample you provided here, you might leverage a [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) (TGT) to negate the extensions you need to match:

```
/((?:https?(?:%3A%2F%2F|:\/\/))(?:www\.)?(?:\S+)(?:%2F|\/)(?:(?!\.(?:mp4|mkv|wmv|m4v|mov|avi|flv|webm|flac|mka|m4a|aac|ogg))[^\/])*\.(mp4|mkv|wmv|m4v|mov|avi|flv|webm|flac|mka|m4a|aac|ogg))(?!\/|\.[a-z]{1,3})/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uJ4vA7/3)

The pattern breakdown:

```
(        # Group 1 matching the whole URL
  (?:https?(?:%3A%2F%2F|:\/\/))(?:www\.)?(?:\S+)(?:%2F|\/) # Matching URL part with no spaces up to the last /
  (?:(?!\.(?:mp4|mkv|wmv|m4v|mov|avi|flv|webm|flac|mka|m4a|aac|ogg))[^\/])* # TGT matching up to the extension
  \.(mp4|mkv|wmv|m4v|mov|avi|flv|webm|flac|mka|m4a|aac|ogg) # The extension
)
(?!\/|\.[a-z]{1,3}) # Only if not followed with /, or another extension
```

The `(?:(?!\.(?:mp4|mkv|wmv|m4v|mov|avi|flv|webm|flac|mka|m4a|aac|ogg))[^\/])*` TGT matches any character other than `/` that is not the first character of a `.mp4`, `.mkv`, etc. literal character sequences (as the negative lookahead fails the match if its pattern matches the text to the right of the current location in the string.

Comment: Ah! Thank you very much! This seems to work. I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Oops... I ran into a problem where this fails on some inline JavaScript.

Here's the relevant portion of the script: `... video_url: 'http://www.example.com/get_file/1/cb57ee6d73a636f40765752ad5dcca51/17000/17957/17957.mp4/', postfix: '.mp4', ...`

How would I fix this? Also, how can I add `%2F` in addition to the `/` in the TGT as you have so that I can account for encoded strings?

Comment: This string also fails when making the regex case insensitive:

`_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Download1', 'http://test.com/test/test.Mkvmoretest.mkv', '374xjli0na6o']);`

Any ideas on how to fix this? I've tried but, haven't been successful.

Comment: What can `__some__random__string__` be? The problem is that we need to know all the delimiter.  Note that to get rid of Uri escaping, use `decodeURIComponent(string)`

Comment: I actually want to match against both encoded and decoded URLs.

The opening delimiter is easy: `http(s)://`. The closing delimiter is tricky because I don't know what to use. I would assume the file extension itself, but I need to grab the whole URL, not just up to the extension. I guess a space would work but, a space in the URL itself needs to be tolerated.

How do regexes that look for URLs in regular text work? Should it not be nearly the same regex with a file extension added into it?

I'm not trying to catch all URLs, just most of them. What I have will work if it can't be improved.

Comment: I do need to know how to add in the encoded characters though.

Comment: I've found this: https://gist.github.com/gruber/8891611 but, I don't know how to adapt the single line regex to my need nor how to convert it to JavaScript. Not sure if it could help.

Comment: Okay. While it's not what I wanted, I've given up and just decided to match between single or double quotes. I've used `http(s)://` as opening delimiter and either a single or double quote for the closing delimiter. Theoretically a link in HTML source should always be between some kind of quote and as this is a fallback to other ways I detect links, it should suffice.

`((?:https?(?:%3A%2F%2F|:\/\/))(?:www\.)?(?:[^\t\r\n])(?:(?!'|").)*\.(mp4|mkv|wmv|m4v|mov|avi|flv|webm|flac|mka|m4a|aac|ogg))(?!\.[a-z]{1,3})`

This seems to do what I want. Thank you for your patience, response, and guidance.

Comment: It seems we are in different time zones. I see what you mean, I will check the regex above when I am at my desktop.

Comment: I am still having troubles with it so that would be very much appreciated. I thought I had what I wanted in the last comment but, it seems it won't return the full URL between the quotes (like when parameters are after the file extension). It also isn't handling double extensions. I need the full URL between the quotes to be in group one and then the file extension in group two. If I could just get that, then I will give up on what I originally was trying to do as I don't think what I originally wanted is going to be possible. (Which is after-all, why they say not to parse HTML with regexes!)

Comment: Yes, it is a bad idea. If you are sure you need to match these links inside attribute values, and there are no `'`, `"` and `?` inside these links, you can use [`((?:https?(?:%3A%2F%2F|:\/\/))(?:www\.)?(?:(?!%3F)[^'"?])*\.(mp4|mkv|wm‌​v|m4v|mov|avi|flv|webm|flac|mka|m4a|aac|ogg))(?:\/?['"?]|%3F)`](https://regex101.com/r/uJ4vA7/4). Or with a bit enhanced alternation group to avoid redundant backtracking: [`((?:https?(?:%3A%2F%2F|:\/\/))(?:www\.)?(?:(?!%3F)[^'"?])*\.(m(?:p4|k[va]|4[av]|ov)|a(?:vi|ac)|flv|w(?:m‌​v|ebm)|flac|ogg))(?:\/?['"?]|%3F)`](https://regex101.com/r/uJ4vA7/5).

Comment: I really appreciate your help. However, those both have the same problem I described in my last comment: they don't capture the full URL. Something like `"https://test.com/test.mkv?test=test"` will fail because it only matches up to the `?`. I want to capture everything between the quotes, but only if it has one of the extensions I have previously listed and the extension is not followed by a different extension as in `"https://test.com/test.mkv.jpg?test=test"`. So, this should match `"https://test.com/test.mkv?test=test"`, this should not `"https://test.com/test.mkv.jpg?test=test"`.

Comment: Try [`((?:https?(?:%3A%2F%2F|:\/\/))(?:www\.)?(?:(?!%3F)[^'"?])*\.(m(?:p4|k[va]|4[av]|ov)|a(?:vi|ac)|flv|w(?:m‌​v|ebm)|flac|ogg)(?:\/?|(?:\?|%3F)[^"'\n]*))['"]`](https://regex101.com/r/uJ4vA7/6).

Comment: Sorry I've been away for a while. I think this is what I am going for: `((?:https?(?:%3A%2F%2F|:\/\/))(?:www\.)?(?:[^'"])*\.(m(?:p4|k[va]|4[av]|ov)|a(?:vi|ac)|flv|w(?:mv|ebm)|flac|ogg)(?!\.[a-z]{1,4})(?:[^'"](?!\.[a-z]{1,4}))*?)['"]`. I built it based off of your regexes. The only case I have found it can't handle is when an image extensions is after the `?`. I don't know how to make it tolerate a case like `http://test.com/test/extension1.Mkvextension2.mkv?=extension3.jpg` but, I'm not worried about it. Thank you for all your help.